# свойство align-content не работает

Tags: css, flexbox

Здравствуйте! У меня не работает свойство `align-content` Вот на [этом сайте](http://html5.by/blogdemo/flexbox/flex-direction-multiline.html) работает. У меня не работает. Вот код.

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.super {
  height: 600px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #F00;
}
.main {
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid #00F;
}
.a1,
.a2,
.a3 {
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #FFF;
}
.a1 {
  background-color: #ff6600;
}
.a2 {
  background-color: #8ccb58;
}
.a3 {
  background-color: #2b689c;
}
.fl-container-wrap {
  /*многострочный режим*/
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /*выравнивание по вертикали, работает только в многострочном режиме*/
  align-content: center;
}
.fl-container {
  display: flex;
  /*направление главной оси*/
  flex-direction: row;
  /*выравнивание по главной оси*/
  justify-content: flex-start;
  /*выравнивание по поперечной оси*/
  align-items: flex-start;
}
```

```html
<div class="super fl-container-wrap">

  <div class="main fl-container">
    <div class="a1">1</div>
    <div class="a2">2</div>
    <div class="a3">3</div>
  </div>


  <div class="main fl-container">
    <div class="a1">1</div>
    <div class="a2">2</div>
    <div class="a3">3</div>
  </div>


  <div class="main fl-container">
    <div class="a1">1</div>
    <div class="a2">2</div>
    <div class="a3">3</div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Три блока должны быть по центру `align-content: center;`, а ничего не происходит.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Если кто сталкивался с такой проблемой, подскажите. Заранее спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.super {
  height: 600px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #F00;
}
.main {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid #00F;
}
.a1,
.a2,
.a3 {
  height: 200px;
  width: 50px;
  padding: 10px;
  color: #FFF;
}
.a1 {
  background-color: #ff6600;
}
.a2 {
  background-color: #8ccb58;
}
.a3 {
  background-color: #2b689c;
}
.fl-container-wrap {
  display: flex;
  /*многострочный режим*/
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
.fl-container {
  display: flex;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>New Страница</title>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="super fl-container-wrap">

    <div class="main fl-container">
      <div class="a1">1</div>
      <div class="a2">2</div>
      <div class="a3">3</div>
    </div>


    <div class="main fl-container">
      <div class="a1">1</div>
      <div class="a2">2</div>
      <div class="a3">3</div>
    </div>


    <div class="main fl-container">
      <div class="a1">1</div>
      <div class="a2">2</div>
      <div class="a3">3</div>

    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Второй пример

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
html {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
.super {
  height: 600px;
  margin: 10px;
  border: 1px solid #F00;
}
.a1,
.a2,
.a3 {
  padding: 10px;
  color: #FFF;
}
.a1 {
  background-color: #ff6600;
}
.a2 {
  background-color: #8ccb58;
}
.a3 {
  background-color: #2b689c;
}
.fl-container-wrap {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <title>New Страница</title>
  <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" />
</head>

<body>
  <div class="super fl-container-wrap">
    <div class="a1">1</div>
    <div class="a2">Opportunity is missed by most people because it is dressed in overalls and looks like work.</div>
    <div class="a3">3</div>
    <div class="a1">1</div>
    <div class="a2">2</div>
    <div class="a3">Work is a necessary evil to be avoided.
Mark Twain</div>
    <div class="a1">1</div>
    <div class="a2">2</div>
    <div class="a3">3</div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Уважаемый stackanon, речь идет о многострочном режиме flex-wrap: wrap; и о выравнивании по вертикали в многострочном режиме свойством align-content: center; В своем вопросе я даже дал ссылку на сайт, где это показано.

Comment: Могли бы вы приложить картинку, желаемого конечного результата? Ссылка на сайт не дает ясности.

Comment: @Anton у `.fl_container` поставьте `align-items: center;` и будут элементы у вас по центру по вертикали

Comment: @Anton изменил пример добавил `.fl-container-wrap` `display: flex` и `flex-flow: column wrap;`

Comment: http://html5.by/blogdemo/flexbox/flex-direction-multiline.html

Comment: Ребята, Вы пытаетесь выровнять по центру другими способами. Я это и сам могу сделать. Вот вверху привел ссылку. Я разбираю тему многострочный режим flex-wrap, только в этом режиме работает свойство align-content. С помощью его я хочу выровнять, а не с помощью других свойств. Как это делается, перейдите по ссылке и посмотрите.

Comment: @Anton посмотрите второй пример. можете развернуть на всю страницу и изменять ширину окна.